# How to install teletype package in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

[image][image]I want to install [teletype package for atom for real-time collaboration](https://teletype.atom.io/)

but package installer doesn't find this package to install. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What version of atom do you have installed?

Comment: It's the latest version of atom.And  I can't install any package in it.

Comment: Does it provide any error messages or logs?

Comment: Yes, it shows only this message(Searching for “teletype” failed.Show output…).

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME.

Comment: Can you show the output then, please?

Comment: Just now i upload the pic in the question. Hope you could help me to fix this problem. Still I am thankful to your efforts.

Comment: Click on Show Output, and paste that.  We're looking for error messages.  Other stuff doesn't help.

Comment: Just now I uploaded the pic of show output. Plz, check the pic I uploaded above just now.

Comment: This is the show output message

"Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output…
write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 10
101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:"

Comment: Are you behind a proxy (at work, for instance)?

Comment: I tried to install at my home as well as at my office too. But couldn't do.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://discuss.atom.io/t/cant-install-packages-from-inside-atom/10971/4

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you don't have the correct version of Atom installed.  For teletype, you need at least version 1.22, and then follow the installation instructions [here](https://atom.io/packages/teletype).

Comment: Actually, I found that I can't install any package in it. I already reinstalled it too.